# Collect streamed data into an angular app

Tags: angular, streaming

Assuming that I have a `Flask` backend streaming data bit by bit, following something like:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import json

from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS( app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    def gen():
        for i in cycle(range(1,10)):
            yield json.dumps( {"new_val":i})
            sleep(1)
    return Response( gen())


app.run( port=5000, debug=True)
```

How can I collect this data in something like an `Observable` on an Angular 5-6-7 app? I have tried playing with `httpClientModule` and done some research but   I did not find any working example.

Comment: HttpClientModule isn't going to do the trick. Yes the RESTful methods return Observables, but they do so to enable cancelling, not for pushing multiple payloads of data.

You probably want to do something with websockets.

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

This might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use socket.io client api for this 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

tutorial for this library with angular 2+
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/socket.io-with-rxjs-in-angular-2.0

and check how to implement it on flask backend

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClientModule` is not what you'll need to use for this.  It will be best to use RxJs's Websocket library.  That library will make this much easier, assuming you know how to set up your backend to accept a Websocket.  If you're worried about the amount of data over the wire, you could also utilize protocol headers, specifically Google's 'protobuf' library.  That can be found here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/